# Why bitcoin's generator point does not satisfy Elliptic Curve Cryptography equation?

Tags: python, cryptography, secp256k1

This is my Python program:

```py
Acurve = 0
Bcurve = 7
Gx = 0x79BE667EF9DCBBAC55A06295CE870B07029BFCDB2DCE28D959F2815B16F81798 
Gy = 0x483ADA7726A3C4655DA4FBFC0E1108A8FD17B448A68554199C47D08FFB10D4B8

print(Gy**2 == Gx**3 + Bcurve)
print(Gy**2)
print(Gx**3 + Bcurve)
```

This is the output:

```
False
1067362225016502275772194909503713869376985974142797512091458491530306631211206623652669436957676354343630306950631573032330832513385319878364322508915776
166977061698153803977729810299616665720111080589888563362701662779994291659333477169534477572723704285154275133397811778652651956291844366636068483203593094558427352525126936769086968791554813695916119291254705683450242657305024007
```

Why is the equation not satisfied for the generator point?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The secp256k1 arithmetic is defined over the finite field of integers modulo *2<sup>256</sup> - 2<sup>32</sup> - 977*.

The following code works:

```py
M = 2**256 - 2**32 - 977
Acurve = 0
Bcurve = 7
Gx = 0x79BE667EF9DCBBAC55A06295CE870B07029BFCDB2DCE28D959F2815B16F81798 
Gy = 0x483ADA7726A3C4655DA4FBFC0E1108A8FD17B448A68554199C47D08FFB10D4B8

print((Gy**2 - Gx**3 - Bcurve) % M == 0)
print(Gy**2 % M)
print((Gx**3 + Bcurve) % M)
```

with output:

```
True
32748224938747404814623910738487752935528512903530129802856995983256684603122
32748224938747404814623910738487752935528512903530129802856995983256684603122
```